# Does Spring STS 3.7 support grails extension

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Does Spring STS 3.7 on Eclipse (mars) 4.5 support grails integration. In this version of STS dashboard, 'Grails Support' extension not available.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Grails IDE extension is no longer supported and doesn't ship with new versions of the Spring Tool Suite anymore (as mentioned in the n&n documentation). However the last version of GGTS (which includes the Grails support) is still available from here: https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all.

The discontinued development of the GGTS distribution (including Groovy-Eclipse and the Grails IDE) is described and discussed here: http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v364/NewAndNoteworthy.html

Comment: as a small exception to this announcement, we finally updated Groovy-Eclipse to Eclipse 4.5 and therefore STS 3.7.0, but additional activities are not on the schedule at the moment.